# r dplyr summarise multiple factors counts

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe I want to summarise, using dplyr. In the dataframe there are multiple factors and I want to report the counts of each factor level summarized per group.

Is there a way to do the following using dplyr without having to name each factor level in the summarise statement.

library(dplyr)

```
set.seed(123)

s <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)
s <- factor(s,0:1,c('M','F'))
a <- sample(1:4,100,TRUE)
a <- factor(a,1:4,c('oldest','old','young','youngest'))
w <- rnorm(100,40,10)
g <- rep(1:2,each=50)

df <- data.frame(sex=s, age=a, weight=w, group=g)



sm <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(
  male = sum(ifelse(sex=='M',1,0))
  ,female = sum(ifelse(sex=='F',1,0))
  ,youngest = sum(ifelse(age=='youngest',1,0))
  ,young = sum(ifelse(age=='young',1,0))
  ,old = sum(ifelse(age=='old',1,0))
  ,oldest = sum(ifelse(age=='oldest',1,0))
  ,weight = mean(weight)
)

print(t(sm))
```

result:

```
        [,1]     [,2]
group     1.000  2.00000
male     29.000 24.00000
female   21.000 26.00000
youngest 12.000  8.00000
young    13.000 17.00000
old      12.000 18.00000
oldest   13.000  7.00000
weight   37.461 40.38807
```

Comment: What is the `x` in the second line?

Comment: You can avoid the `ifelse` and do the `sum` directly on the logical vector

Comment: x is a typo that should be s... changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dplyr (albeit in a circuitous, hacky way!):

```
df %>%
    mutate(row_number1 = row_number(), row_number2 = row_number()) %>%
    spread(sex, row_number1) %>%
    spread(age, row_number2) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, 1)), -weight) %>%
    mutate(count = 1) %>%
    summarize_each(funs(sum)) %>%
    mutate(weight = weight / (count)) %>%
    select(-count) %>%
    t()
```

result:

```
           [,1]     [,2]
group     1.000  2.00000
weight   37.461 40.38807
M        25.000 28.00000
F        25.000 22.00000
oldest   13.000  7.00000
old      12.000 18.00000
young    13.000 17.00000
youngest 12.000  8.00000
```

Comment: Very hacky, but I like it.

Comment: Thanks! I might consider splitting the factor and continuous variables, so the manual mean calculation can be evaded.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that for factors you want tables, and for numbers (e.g. `weight`) you want the mean.

This, not using dplyr, does what you want, though the result may not be formatted how you like.

```
sapply(df, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) table(x, df$group) else tapply(x, df$group, mean))
```

You might also want to look at the `reporttools` package, including `tableNominal` and `tableContinuous`.

Comment: your script produces the right numbers, but the goal of my script is producing a publishable table.

Comment: I suspected as much. Have you looked into reporttools?